# In highchart how to show y axis values in reverse order

Tags: highcharts

I want to show Maximum value of y axis in the origin place: like shown in the below image[image]

As shown in the graph above, Y axis's top value is mimimum i.e 0(zero).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set `yAxis.reversed = True` as per the demo:

http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/yaxis-reversed